# How to determine amount of time it takes for a system to completely boot up?

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2003

In my company, we run several startup scripts when users login - in addition to the various TSR applications.

I attempted to create a script (vbscript) that would allow me to output the the two times (or calculated time) into a text file located on the network share.

This would allow me to trend startup times - since I get complaints constantly related to this.

Anyone seen/created/thought about this concept?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is for windows, might want to try this BootTimer program someone wrote:

http://www.planetsoft.org/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Such information is probably already being captured in the system event log, which [you can read](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785425(WS.10).aspx) over the network.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a software named [BootRacer](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/) to measure it.

Comment: Goodness, says it takes 4m01s to get to desktop. Then wait for Outlook to start. My users may be correct this time...now I need to find how to speed up Windows XP boot on a Win2k3 network.

Comment: Try to set to inactive all the process that are not needed, then clean the registry. You may be also interested in ask this question in superuser.com or serverfault.com. There you will be able to get more focused help about the question.